# Problemas para eliminar un registro de una tabla con ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, json

veran estoy intentado borrar el registro de una tabla con Ajax, dicha tabla esta hecha por medio de DataTable, sin embargo el botón de eliminar no me quiere funcionar, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
    ReferenceError: BorrarSeccion is not defined
```

Aqui dejo mi codigo:

Codigo javascript para cargar tabla y el boton de Borrar

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

         listarSeccion();

          function BorrarSeccion(id)

       {

       bootbox.confirm("¿Esta Seguro que quiere eliminar esta Seccion 
          Electoral?", function(result){
          if(result){
           $.post("../Controlador/EliminarSeccion.php", {id : id}, function(e){
              console.log(e);


                }); //fin del ajax
            } //primer if

            });

          } //fin de la funcion




           });

           var listarSeccion = function() {
            var table = $("#tablaSeccion").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
           "method": "POST",
            "url": "../Controlador/ListarSecciones.php",

              },
             "columns": 
              [
              {"data": "Nombre_Sec"},
              {"data": "Acciones"}
                ]
               });

                }
```

codigo php que lista los registros:

```
    session_start();

                        include_once "../Modelo/conexion2.php";
                        include_once "../Modelo/Secciones.php";

                $objSeccion = new Secciones();

                            $resultado = $objSeccion->Listar();

                    $arreglo = Array();

                    while ($data = $resultado->fetch_object()) 

                    {


                    $arreglo ["data"][] = array( 
                 "Nombre_Sec" => $data->Seccion,
                 "Acciones" => '<a href="EditarSeccionVista.php?idSec=' . $data->idsec . '"><i class="fa fa-edit" id="iconoEditar"></i></a>'.'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="BorrarSeccion('.$data->idsec.')" id="modalSeccion"><i class="fa fa-edit" id="iconoBorrar"></i> </button>');
                    }

                echo json_encode($arreglo);

                    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
                    mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Los datos se cargan en la tabla perfectamente. La funcionalidad para editar los registros funciona perfectamente. El problema es a la hora de eliminar. La alerta no se muestra y me sale ese error en consola. 
Intente usar un modal de bootstrap, este abre pero igual me sigue mostrando el mismo error de que BorrarSeccion is not defined y no me elimina nada ya que el idsec nunca se carga en el boton...
Yo lo que quiero es poder borrar el registro sin tener que estar saltando de pagina en pagina, sino hacerlo con ajax.

Anteriormente he realizado este tipo de procedimientos, y me funciona bien, sin problemas elimino registros, pero esta vez me da este error pero no logro ver donde esta el problema.

Podrian echarme una mano?

----------------------------------SOLUCION-------------------------------------

El error estaba en el codigo javascript.
La función BorrarSeccion(id) se movio fuera del $(document) y el codigo funciona a la perfección, gracias al aporte del usuario mencionado en los comentarios.

codigo javascript corregido

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

         listarSeccion();

           });

           var listarSeccion = function() {
            var table = $("#tablaSeccion").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
           "method": "POST",
            "url": "../Controlador/ListarSecciones.php",

              },
             "columns": 
              [
              {"data": "Nombre_Sec"},
              {"data": "Acciones"}
                ]
               });

                }

            function BorrarSeccion(id)

       {

       bootbox.confirm("¿Esta Seguro que quiere eliminar esta Seccion 
          Electoral?", function(result){
          if(result){
           $.post("../Controlador/EliminarSeccion.php", {id : id}, function(e){
              console.log(e);


                }); //fin del ajax
            } //primer if

            });

          } //fin de la funcion
```

Comment: Podrias intentar definir el metodo `function BorrarSeccion(id)` fuera del `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: Si, efectivamente ese era el error que estaba dejando pasar por alto. Funcionó. Gracias por tu ayuda.